# how to detect the virus and malware from drupal website

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-7

I have created my website in Drupal7. I have updated all software to the latest and recommended versions, like set php.ini detectives to the best security settings,  and I have given upload folders strict permissions, so as nothing executable is uploaded to the server, and I am doing regular database/data backups.

But my website still infected by virus and malware.

So I want to know that what kinds of tools I can use to find out the virus and malware from my website.

Can anybody provide me solution for that?

Comment: When you did all this? After the site got infected or since always? Securing your server is up to you. There are unlimited tutorials out there. And about Drupal, well you got your answer already https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270815/how-to-detect-the-virus-malware-from-drupal-website – alway update to the latest versions *before your site gets infected*. In the end you have opened a security hole in one of your custom modules. How to guide you on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to prevent files from virus : https://www.drupal.org/project/clamav